# Solving a first order non-linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I encountered a problem solving the following equation: $$t^2dy/dt+2ty-y^3=0$$
I have already tried the following steps, but to no avail:

1)Separation of variables

2.1)Integration Factor of 1 variable.

2.2)Integration Factor of 2 variables.

3)Transposing the equation and find a solution for x.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite the equation as

$$\frac{d}{dt} (t^2 y) = y^3$$

Multiply both sides by $t^6$:

$$t^6 \frac{d}{dt} (t^2 y) = (t^2 y)^3$$

or

$$\frac{d(t^2 y)}{(t^2 y)^3} = \frac{dt}{t^6}$$

Integrating,

$$-\frac12 \frac{1}{(t^2 y)^2} = -\frac15 \frac{1}{t^5} - C$$

Rearrange to get $y(t)$:

$$y(t) = \sqrt{\frac{5 t}{2+5 C t^5}}$$

where $C$ is a constant of integration.